# I am keep getting the error "" Type '[AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType]' has no member 'builtInWideAngleCamera' ""

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I am keep getting the error:

> Type '[AVCaptureDevice.DeviceType]' has no member 'builtInWideAngleCamera'

But I am not sure how to change this code. My Xcode version is 14.3. Iphone being 14 pro.
This is the code I wrote:

```swift
if let availableDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: .builtInWideAngleCamera, mediaType: 
    AVMediaTypeVideo, position: .back).devices {
    captureDevice = availableDevices.first
    beginSession()
```

This is the only error. Please let me know the simplest way to fix this!

I think a simple alternative would do, but I do not even know the basics. Please help me fix.

Comment: have you tried just this: `let availableDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera],
                                                                        mediaType: .video,
                                                                        position: .back).devices`

Comment: I did... but it created more errors. This was the only error by the way.

Answer (score 0):

The primary issue is that the `devices` parameter is expecting an array, not a single value.

After that is fixed you'll get an error about the `mediaType` parameter. You need to specify a valid `AVMediaType` value.

Finally, the `devices` property of `AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession` is not optional so you don't need `if let` there, but calling `first` on an array gives an optional so you need `if let` there.

The fixed code would be:

```swift
let availableDevices = AVCaptureDevice.DiscoverySession(deviceTypes: [.builtInWideAngleCamera], mediaType: .video, position: .back).devices
if let captureDevice = availableDevices.first {
    beginSession()
}
```

Comment: Yayy!!!!!! Now there is no error but the camera still not popping up..

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to indicate that you question has been solved by clicking the checkmark next to the answer that best solved your issue. You can also upvote helpful answers as well (though I think you need at least a couple of points of reputation for that). If you can't figure out your camera issue after trying a few things, post a new question with all relevant details.